# Plasma 5.13 in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, kde, versions, plasma-5

[Plasma 5.13](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/kde-plasma-5130) is said to have better Kwin performance and many other improvements.

Can it be installed and can it run in Kubuntu 18.04?

The upgrade doesn't sound very abrupt, it should be from 5.12 to 5.13.

Adding the Kubuntu Backports ppa only brought me 5.12.5.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

---

### NOTE JULY 2TH 2018:

**I DO NOT RECOMMEND INSTALLING IT. AT THE DATE OF THE FIRST POST AND OF THIS EDIT 5.13 IS UNSTABLE ENOUGH FOR ME TO AVOID RECOMMENDING IT - AS I HAVE TESTED IT IN NEON ITSELF MEANWHILE.**

At the date of this edit Neon is using Plasma 5.13 on an Ubuntu 16.04-base.

Comment: Well, Plasma 5.14 is now available, but it is not available from the PPAs for Ubuntu Bionic (not yet). 

One way to try Plasma 5.14 is to do the following: Change sources from "bionic" to "cosmic" in "/etc/apt/sources.list". You could also add two Kubuntu ppas, then update the sources, and just upgrade the KDE/Plasma packages from an application like "Synaptic". Well, you will need to be careful to not break any other packages and resolve any broken dependencies. I am successfully running Plasma 5.14 on Bionic presently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the Kubuntu forums**

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73757-plasma-5-13-0?p=416441&viewfull=1#post416441

acheron:

> ...we are waiting on the required new Qt version to be done for
>   Ubuntu.
>
> Plasma 5.13 will get a 5.13.1 and 5.13.2 rapid bugfix update releases
>   in the next 2 weeks, so even if we don't get the initial 5.13.0 done,
>   that may not be a bad thing if we go straight to versions that have
>   had a round or 2 of bugfixes.

There is no such thing as the 'Neon ppa'. Your 'add-apt-repository ...' line is adding the Kubuntu ppa backport to your system. As the Kubuntu developer 'acheron' told the Plasma 5.13 will need at least the Qt 5.10. When the Ubuntu 18.10 has the newer Qt and the Plasma 5.13.X they will be backported to the Kubuntu backports ppa.

The Neon has own KDE repositories: https://archive.neon.kde.org . In the past the brave users have been mixing the Ubuntu and the Neon repositories: https://gist.github.com/nihathrael/7429eeb8d539c4c8e0ade03269b3f95a . BUT ! as told you are doing it at your own risk.

**“Kubuntu Package Archives” team**

There are: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa

[image]

Note the warnings !

Comment: sorry for my confusing post. the ppa is the kubuntu backports, I get it now